# ng-blur in Karma on Firefox

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, firefox, blur, karma-runner

In a Karma.js unit test for an Angular.js directive, I encountered weird inconsitency in behaviour between Chrome and Firefox.

Directive has a template, and this template contains a form with some inputs. I want to unit test whether there will be some scope method called after first input loses focus.

So, I have this test:

```
describe('Firefox weirdness.', function() {
  var $scope, compiled;
  var template = '<dir></dir>';

  beforeEach(function() {
    module('templates');
    module('App');

    inject(function($compile, $rootScope) {
      $scope = $rootScope.$new();
      compiled = $compile(template)($scope);
      angular.element(compiled).appendTo(document.body);
      $scope.$apply();
    });
  });

  it('Shows weirdness.', function() {
    var i1 = compiled.find('input[name="i1"]'),
        i2 = compiled.find('input[name="i2"]'),
        executed = false;

    // This method is never called on Firefox.
    // On Chrome it works flawlessly.
    $scope.doStuff = function() {
      executed = true;
    };

    // Focus first input, then second.
    // It doesn't help if I delay them via setTimeouts,
    // or by digesting the scope.
    angular.element(i1).focus();
    angular.element(i2).focus();

    // This line fails.
    expect(executed).to.be.true;
  });
});
```

And the directive looks like this (it's jade):

```
form(name="form")
  input(name="i1", ng-blur="doStuff()")
  input(name="i2")
```

While my JS code is:

```
describe('Firefox weirdness.', function() {
var app = angular.module('App', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
   $scope.doStuff = function() {
     console.log('Stuff done!');
   };
});

app.directive('dir', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: 'dir.html'
  };
});
```

What is wrong? The test will pass on Chrome, but on Firefox - it fails. I tried to use some timeouts etc. to rule out some timing issues, but it would still fail. Can someone explain why and hint as to how to fix that?

I use Angular.js 1.2, Mocha + Chai and karma-ng-jade2js-preprocessor to put templates as a separate Angular module (for testing, to avoid Angular trying to load them asynchronously).

I've put a little example in this repo: https://github.com/kamituel/firefox-blur-weirdness. You can try it out by cloning, installing npm dependencies, and running `./karma start karma.conf`. As a result you'll see Chrome test passing, and Firefox one fail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can actually trigger the blur event instead

```
    angular.element(i1).focus();
```

Maybe triggering the focus event on another input does not trigger the blur event of the previously focused input in Firefox

If you forget about Angular, this will also fails in Firefox

```
it('Shows weirdness.', function () {
    var i1 = compiled.find('input[name="i1"]'),
        i2 = compiled.find('input[name="i2"]'),
        executed = false;

    angular.element(i1).bind('blur', function () {
        executed = true;
    });

    angular.element(i1).focus();
    angular.element(i2).focus();

    expect(executed).to.be.true;
});
```

whereas this does not

```
it('Shows weirdness.', function () {
        var i1 = compiled.find('input[name="i1"]'),
        i2 = compiled.find('input[name="i2"]'),
        executed = false;

    angular.element(i1).bind('blur', function () {
        executed = true;
    });

    angular.element(i1).blur();


    expect(executed).to.be.true;
});
```

Comment: Yes, this would explain this behaviour. I've upvoted your answer, and if no other answer pops up in the meantime, I'll award the bounty. Thanks!